# Tuples screwing with me

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to append everything but 'A' from tuple into new_tuple

```
>>> tuple=('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
>>> for i in tuple:
        new_tuple=()
        if i!='A':
            new_tuple+=(i,)

>>> new_tuple
('D',)
```

It only prints ('D',) instead of ('B','C','D')

But it's funny how you can loop through every element and print it....

```
>>> for i in tuple:
        print (i)   
A
B
C
D
```

Comment: Are trying to filter out certain values, or are you just wanting to get all but the first element of the tuple?

Answer (score 2):

You reinitialize `new_tuple` through each iteration. Put `new_tuple=()` before the loop and it should work.

```
tuple = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')

new_tuple = ()
for i in tuple:
    if i != 'A':
        new_tuple += (i,)

print new_tuple
```